# Audio Sync Issues on playback via thumb drive

Tags: video-editor, final-cut-pro, audio-quality

I've got an audio sync issue with a .mov file during playback via thumb drive on a samsung tv. I exported the clip using QuickTime Conversion, H.264 compression with 48 KHz for the sample rate.

I am currently using the same settings on multiple clips on the same playback devices (Samsung tv) all other clips are working fine.

Anyone know if there is a different compression type I should use? I'm not sure if that is the problem since all other clips are working fine. The sync issue has just started today.

The original video sources are being ripped from YouTube.

TIA!
Mike

Comment: What's the data rate of the video clip? Does this happen on a particular thumb drive?

Answer (score 1):

The answer stems from the combination of the speed of the flash drive and the data rate of the video. The video and audio in most codec are decoded separately once streamed to the computer from the flash drive. Now when the flash drive can't keep up with the speed the video is supposed to be playing then the audio or the video get ahead because the flash drive cannot serve both at the same time. Time for a faster flash drive.